# Can 27x1 wheels fit on 27x11/4?

Tags: tire

Will a 27 x 1 wheel fit on a bike which had a 27 x 1-1/4? A back wheel with same size of cassette.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. when you say wheel, do you mean to say tire?

Answer (score 1):

According to [www.sheldonbrown.com](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tyre-sizing.html) the rim is the same size. 27x"1 and anything -  except 1 1/2 is an Iso630  wheel so the same size.

The frame dropout spacing will need to match the hub axle width (O.L.D). Another useful [Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html) web page here

https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html